# Do Mage Armor, Robes of Archmagi, and Dragon Mask stack?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, armor-class

Would the spell mage armor stack with [robes of the archmagi](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Items:Robe%20of%20the%20Archmagi#h-Robe%20of%20the%20Archmagi) and/or the [dragon mask](http://www.tribality.com/2014/11/05/dragon-masks-tyranny-of-dragons/) from HotDQ?

Comment: [Related] [Can the AC bonuses of Bracers of Defense and Black Dragon Mask (HotDQ) stack?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/92417)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Mage Armor and the Robes of the Archmagi both provide an *alternative* way to calculate your Base AC (instead of the default 10 + Dex Base AC everyone gets). You can only have one Base AC, so they do not stack — if you have both active you must choose one Base AC or the other, usually whichever is better, and cannot combine them in any way.

The Dragon Mask however provides an AC bonus, and stacks with any Base AC. Hence, either of these combinations do work:

- Mage Armor + Dragon Mask
- Robes of the Archmagi + Dragon Mask